# Nginx Hotliking protection pointing at a specific image (nginx as reverse proxy)

Tags: nginx, hotlinking

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy with apache.

I have added this code to prevent hotlinking, and it is working fine so far.

```
#hotlinking protection
location ~* \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$ {
valid_referers none blocked mydomain.com *.mydomain.com;
    if ($invalid_referer){
    return 403;
    }
}
```

How can I make it so when somebody tries to hotlink an image, instead of a 403 error, he will get a specific anti-hotlinking image?

I tried

```
return 301 h++p://i.imgur.com/mypicturename.png;
```

but it didnt work.

I don't know very much about nginx yet, every help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wrote `h++p` instead of `http`?

Comment: Since it wasn't the real filename, I didn't see the purpose for writing http here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) rule inside of the if instead of the return.

Somthing like

```
rewrite (.*) http://i.imgur.com/mypicturename.png redirect;
```

might do the trick.